# My JavaFX Scene is a mess

Tags: java, xml, javafx, scene

I'm having a very hard time aligning items in my JavaFX scene.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.controller.TableViewController">
    <ScrollPane>
        <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1100.0" snapToPixel="false" styleClass="100">
        </TableView>
    </ScrollPane>
    <ToolBar maxHeight="35.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="1200" style="-fx-background-color: #8C0000;">
        <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <Image url="@../images/qmit-search-toolbar-logo.png" />
        </ImageView>
        <TextArea fx:id="linkInput" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="250.0" />
        <TextArea fx:id="keywordInput" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="100.0" />
        <Button fx:id="buttonSearch" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="100.0" text="Search QMIT" />
    </ToolBar>
</Pane>
```

My goal is to have a ToolBar with a logo, two input text fields, and a button. Beneath, a table that is centered in the screen. What am I doing wrong here that I end up with such a tangled mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Pane` does no layout on its own.

(As an aside, note that a `TableView` provides its own scrolling functionality: don't wrap it in a scroll pane.)

Use, for example, a [`BorderPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.controller.TableViewController">
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1100.0" snapToPixel="false" styleClass="100">
        </TableView>
    </center>
    <top>
        <ToolBar maxHeight="35.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="1200" style="-fx-background-color: #8C0000;">
            <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                <Image url="@../images/qmit-search-toolbar-logo.png" />
            </ImageView>
            <TextArea fx:id="linkInput" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="250.0" />
            <TextArea fx:id="keywordInput" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="100.0" />
            <Button fx:id="buttonSearch" maxHeight="30.0" maxWidth="100.0" text="Search QMIT" />
        </ToolBar>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

The Oracle JavaFX Tutorial has a [section on layout panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).

Comment: Thank you. And thanks for the suggestions. I also noticed that adding prefWidth and prefHeight streamlines it a bit. Without those values, for example, the ToolBar is unnecessarily tall.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a VBox instead of a Pane as basis and add onto that first the toolbar with TextFields instead of  TextAreas and then add the ScrollPane with your TableView

Answer (score -1):

Using the JavaFX Scene Builder is a lot simpler than writing the FXML manually.

It can be downloaded from the Oracle website.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html

Comment: Do not download this completely outdated SceneBuilder from Oracle. SceneBuilder is not maintained by Gluon and you can download it here: http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all. Even if you use (a recent version of) SceneBuilder, you still have to make the choice as to which layout pane to use. SceneBuilder would not in any way help to choose to use something sensible (a `BorderPane` or `VBox`) here - in fact, it may even lead you to believe that positioning things in a `Pane` would work, and that would of course break horribly if the user resized the window.